# regular expression with substitution and options

Tags: regex

I’m trying to write a regular expression to modify phone numbers.  If its an international number (non-US), I want the `+` symbol kept (`%2B` after being URL-encoded).  If it’s a domestic number, the `%2B` should be stripped, and changed for 11 digit format with a `1` at the front.

The 4 use cases are:

- `%2B2125551000`  becomes `0112125551000`(This should be seen as an international number, since it starts with `+[2-9]` – replace `+` with `011`)
- `%2B12125551000` becomes `12125551000` (Since this is `+1`, it is a domestic number, strip off the `+`)
- `2125551000` becomes `12125551000` (Domestic number as there is no `+`)
- `12125551000` becomes `12125551000` (Domestic number as there is no `+`)

I have been trying to test this out using *sed* on Linux:

The expression which does the matching is:

```
((%2B)|)?((1)|)?([0-9]{10})
```

However, I don't necessarily always need all 5 arguments.  I only need the `%2B` to be kept if the string is `%2B[2-9]`.

```
$ for line in %2B2125551000 %2B12125551000 12125551000 2125551000;do echo $line | sed -r 's/^((%2B|))?((1)|)?([0-9]{10})/one:\1   two:\2   three:\3   four:\4   five:\5/';done
one:%2B   two:%2B   three:   four:   five:2125551000
one:%2B   two:%2B   three:1   four:1   five:2125551000
one:   two:   three:1   four:1   five:2125551000
one:   two:   three:   four:   five:2125551000
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, let's see, what you want:

```
s/^%2B(?=[2-9])/011/ || # this will do first rule and change %2B to 011  
s/^%2B(?=1)// ||        # this will do second rule and strip off %2B  
s/^(?:[2-9])/1$&/ ;     # this will do third rule and add 1 to the beginning of the number  

# Perl code 
my @all = <DATA>;

for (@all){
    s/^%2B(?=[2-9])/011/ or 
    s/^%2B(?=1)// or
    s/^(?:[2-9])/1$&/ ; 
    print "line is $_ \n";  
}

__DATA__
%2B2125551000
%2B1125551000
225551000
125551000
```

Comment: Hi, that is helpful - thank you., however, I need to do it on one line, as the regex is to be input into a software application.  It seems that I need to do an if-then-else situation, but I'm still not understanding how you backreference fields which might not be present.

Comment: I can use (%2B)?([1-9])?[0-9]+ to check if the input it valid, but its not a simple case of replacing \2 with XXX, because it depends on whether \1 is present or not.

Comment: yes, it is, you are right. my script you can use in one-line, cause this is sequence of 3 substiotutions, which work as `lazy-style`